# Object List<String> take too much memory on RAM

Tags: c#, file, object, memory

I have a text file with Json data, it's size is 140 Mb. I read into List String and i deserialize it with Web.Script.Serialization, then the result object become 450Mb size in RAM memory. And i don't know how it takes too much memory ? (the original text file is 140Mb only)

Does anyone met this problem and give me some explanation?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd have honestly expected even more than 450Mb to be honest...

Comment: Firstly, you should not use `Web.Script.Serialization`, it only exists because of legacy support, there are dozens of better options. Secondly, how can you read a file into a list of strings? Is it multiple JSON docs in a single file? I'm really not sure why ou read it into memory at all.

Comment: Thank @DavidG for your comment.
I need to do searching in a large list of file, i found that read all of files into memory will take less time for searching. This why i read all into object.

Comment: You're right, the file contains Json and some another information.
So the solution is i will try to use another JSON parse, will take my object become lower size ?

Comment: @user2366842 please can you explain for me why it does increase size when i read into object @_@!
I'm new. please.

Comment: @KietPhan Assuming that your text uses an ANSI or other single-byte encoding or UTF-8 which is single-byte if only basic Latin letters and numbers are used and the fact that C# uses UTF-16 internally your strings would at least double in size. Then you have a small overhead of the string class like the holding the string length and header information which should further add 12 bytes to each string. Other than that it really depends on how you measured your 450 MB.

Comment: @ckuri Got it, thanks you so much for explanation !!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your helping,

I'm doing searching string in a large list of file, i found that read all of files into memory will take less time for searching.

But problem is List String takes too much memory on RAM.

This is my conclusion:

1. Use Json.Net instead of Web.Script.Serialization, Json.net will much more faster for serialize and deserialize.
2. Compress String when read file into memory, and then decompress it for using.(Searching will slower but not too much)

https://dotnet-snippets.de/snippet/strings-komprimieren-und-dekomprimieren/1058